# Airflow task triggers successfully but no file uploaded

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm trying to run a simple ETL DAG with Airflow. Airflow shows that the DAG was successfully triggered, but nothing gets uploaded to my computer. When I run the function myself, it works fine.

This is the etl function to extract data from an api, transforms it and loads it to a sqlite datebase file.

```
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import Cursor
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import sqlalchemy
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None


def run_activity_etl():
    DATABASE_LOCATION = "sqlite:///run_activity.sqlite"
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    yesterday = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    #extract
    access_token = "****" #not relevant for my issue
    header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)}
    response = requests.get("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/list.json?afterDate=2021-07-01&sort=asc&offset=0&limit=100", headers=header).json()
    activity_data=pd.json_normalize(response['activities'], sep="_")

    #transform
    subset=['startTime', 'activityName', 'distance', 'duration', 'speed', 'averageHeartRate','calories', 'steps']
    subset_activity_data=activity_data[subset]
    subset_run = subset_activity_data[subset_activity_data['activityName']=='Run']
    subset_run["startTime"]= pd.to_datetime(subset_run["startTime"])
    subset_run["date"] = subset_run["startTime"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    #load
    engine= sqlalchemy.create_engine(DATABASE_LOCATION)
    conn=sqlite3.connect('run_activity.sqlite')
    cursor=conn.cursor()

    sql_query = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS run_activity(
            date VARCHAR(200),
            activityName VARCHAR(200),
            distance VARCHAR(200),
            duration VARCHAR(200),
            speed VARCHAR(200),
            averageHeartRate VARCHAR(200),
            calories VARCHAR(200),
            steps VARCHAR(200),
            startTime VARCHAR(200),
            CONSTRAINT primary_key_constraint PRIMARY KEY (startTime)
        )
        """

    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    print("Opened database successfully")

    try:
        subset_run.to_sql("run_activity", engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
    except:
        print("Data already exists in the database")

    conn.close()
    print("Close database successfully")
```

My DAG file:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from fitbit_api import run_activity_etl


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(0,0,0,0,0),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
    'activity_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='ETL process for Fitbit on running data!',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)


run_etl = PythonOperator(
    task_id='whole_activity_etl',
    python_callable=run_activity_etl,
    dag=dag,
)

run_etl
```

This is the log from airflow:

[Log from airflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebpd4.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have to learn a lot, but I found the solution to my issue. Apparently, the database location should have been: `sqlite:////opt/airflow/dags/run_activity.sqlite` in my case, as this is also written in my docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

Now, this file gets uploaded without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have the following:

```py
try:
    subset_run.to_sql("run_activity", engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
except:
    print("Data already exists in the database")
```

This means it catches any exception that is there. If you remove the `try except` and just run

```py
subset_run.to_sql("run_activity", engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

You will probably see the exception. If you post it here, we can help you further.

Comment: Thank you, however I don't see an exception coming up when changing the code.  The log also don't show any errors as far as I can tell. Moreover, when I run the code without airflow it works completly fine (> it creates the .sqlite file)

Comment: Your database location is `/run_activity.sqlite` in the root folder is that correct? Maybe supply another full path there

Comment: Thanks for helping! Tried that as well `DATABASE_LOCATION = "sqlite:///C:\\Users\\jules\\OneDrive\\Documenten\\Python projects\\run_activity.sqlite" `
but same result: when running the function without airflow it works (creates the file). If I trigger the DAG with airflow it says it triggered successfully, but then no file is created. Also tried it with just writing a csv file, but same "result"...

Comment: Are you sure Airflow has permission to write to that folder? Write a simply PythonOperator that opens a file and write to that same directory to test it. Also not sure here, but I think your full path should be `sqlite://C:\Users\jules\OneDrive\Documenten\Python projects\run_activity.sqlite`

Comment: I have to use the double backslash otherwise it raises an error. If I try to do a simple task (open and write a file to the same directory), I get this error in the Airflow log: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\jules\\OneDrive\\Documenten\\Python projects\\airflow-docker\\dags\\test.csv'` (this file is definitely there) Does this mean Airflow doesn't have  the permission? If so, how can I give Airflow permission? Thanks again!

Comment: Alright thanks for clearing that up. I guess that's a Windows thing :p. What write permission are you trying to write with? (for example `r` means `open('my_file_path', 'r')`? I think this error indicates though that the Airflow process can't write to this specific folder. You might need to open up the folder and give write permissions to everyone on the computer. [Maybe this helps](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373).

Comment: Thanks again! First I tried pandas read_csv, which gave me this error. So I tried this: 

`def testing():
    f =open("C:\\Users\\jules\\Documents\\test.txt", 'w')
    f.write("hello world")
    f.close()
    print("it worked!")`
No error in Airflow log, but nothing happens with the actual file. I followed the steps from your link, should have permission now?